# Firebug console shows just one result

Tags: jquery, firebug, resultset

I am trying to learn jQuery from a book. There are examples in it, but when I try to do the same, the result is not the same. when I run

```
$("p");
```

in Firebug(1.12.8) console, it shows just one paragraph even though there are 4 paragraphs on the page, but in the book the result is a set of all 4 paragraphs. Is this a problem with Firebug version?

**Update:**

Here is my HTML code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset='utf-8'>
    <title>Test | Pro PHP and jQuery</title>
</head>
<body>
    <p>Hello World!</p>
    <p class='foo'>Another paragraph but this one has a class.</p>
    <p><span>This is a span inside a paragraph.</span></p>
    <p id='bar'>Paragraph with an id.
        <span class='foo'>And this sentence is in a span.</span>
    </p>
    <script src='http://www.google.com/jsapi' />
    <script>
    google.load("jquery", "1.4.2");
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

and I am using Firefox 26 and jquery 1.4.2(as in the book).
Also, using jQuery() instead of $() did not work.

**Update:**

Ok, I found that it was a problem about my html. I shouldn't have used the self closing script tag. No problem, now.

Comment: Firebug has its own function called `$`. To be sure you're using jQuery, write `jQuery("p")` instead.

Comment: Could you post the html code as well please? Which versions are you of firefox and jquery are you using?

Comment: @Barış You should post your update as answer, so you can accept it. @IMSoP Firebug doesn't overwrite `$` when it's defined on the page. I.e. on jQuery enabled pages `$` will refer to jQuery, not to the [Command Line API](https://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/Command_Line_API).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I found that it was a problem about my html. I shouldn't have used the self closing script tag. No problem, now. Btw, thank @Sebastian for remembering me to accept my own answer.